# How to wait for bootstrap modal response in angular 13?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, angular14

I am new to angular and trying to call a bootstrap modal and wait for its response, Everything is working, except it is not returning any value:

**PS: I am using bootstrap5 CDN version**

This is my bootstrap.component.ts:

```
  showConfirmation() {
    this.confirmationModal.show();
  }


  closeConfirmation() {
    this.confirmationModal.hide();
  }

  confirmationOk(): boolean {
    this.confirmationModal.hide();
    return true;
  }

  confirmationDeclined(): boolean {
    this.confirmationModal.hide();
    return false;
  }
```

my bootstrap.component.html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary radius-none" (click)="confirmationOk()">Yes</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary radius-none" (click)="confirmationDeclined()">No</button>
```

and my parent.component.ts:

```
 let x = await this.popupModal.showConfirmation()
 console.log(x) //-------No value here
```

I just want to call `this.popupModal.showConfirmation()` and then wait for the confirmation button to be click and get the response value. Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try defining an observable in your modal component and return observable when you open the modal and subscribe in the parent component. So in your `bootstrap.component.ts`

```
  _onClose:Subject<any>=new Subject<any>();

  showConfirmation() {
    this.confirmationModal.show();
    retrun {
     onClose:()=>this._onClose;
    }
  }


  closeConfirmation() {
    this.confirmationModal.hide();
    this._onClose.next(false);
  }

  confirmationOk(): boolean {
    this.confirmationModal.hide();
    this._onClose.next(true);
  }

  confirmationDeclined(): boolean {
    this.confirmationModal.hide();
    this._onClose.next(false);
  }
```

then in your parent component

```
this.popupModal.showConfirmation().onClose().subscribe(value=> {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: got an error: TypeError: _this.popupModal.showConfirmation(...).onClose is not a function

Comment: can you try assigning value to some variable and debug like `let x=this.popupModal.showConfirmation()` then `console.log(x)` and see if you see onClose funtion there

Comment: yes but it is inside __zone_symbol__value{onClose....}

Comment: it should work can you create a stack blitz example for this

Comment: Im trying but I cant add a bootstrap cdn in stackblits

Comment: ohh, I need to  close and open vistual studio for the changes to take effect. It is working now